SAP NetWeaver. Unable to get handle to iamodell.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
I am trying to install SAP NetWeaver demo (7.52 SP04) on my Oracle Virtual Machine via OpenSUSE 15.5 Linux Gnome.
When running install.sh file I get the error:

################################################################################# 
Unable to get handle to iamodell.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
################################################################################# 
Error: sapinst has finished with an error code, please find logs in /tmp/sapinst_instdir 
Error code: 20

I tried to install the libnsl file manually following OpenSUSE instructions:
https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=libnsl&project=spins%3Ainvis%3Abenno

zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/spins:invis:benno/15.5/spins:invis:benno.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install libnsl

Repo was successfully added, libnsl was installed.
Command zypper search libnsl showed following:

But I am still getting the same error when trying to reinstall and launch install.sh file.
How can I add and then open this libnsl file to complete the installation?

Did you check that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 environment variable contains the library's location?

libnsl.so.1 actually meant libnsl1
So, sudo zypper install libnsl1 was the solution.

not working on OpenSUSE 15.5, try to install on OpenSUSE 15.4

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
